# How do I dynamically use include in a Flask Template?

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

I have a flask backend sending data to the client. Some JS on the client side then utilizes that data to construct a page that includes one row of data and another area below the row that has a d3 display with clickable nodes.

The nodes have different properties corresponding to different models in the backend and different html templates. Given a type, when clicked, a different html template is presented in the row above.

How do I set the template from the JS? I tried doing something like:

```
$("#div_id").innerHTML = "{% set obj = " + obj + "%}{% include '" + obj_template_file + "' %}"
```

That (perhaps of course) didn't work. After taking care of escaping, it just displays that string. I thought of dirty ways of doing this like using hide and show liberally but that doesn't seem wise.

Comment: Can you adjust the code so that it makes a call to a function within your app that takes these `obj*` variables are request arguments and returns the rendered template as part of an ajax call?

Comment: Are you saying make an ajax request everytime one of the nodes are clicked?

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know the complexity of your application. It looks like you want to render templates mostly based on data that is calculated within Javascript, so either send that as a batch request, returning the rendered templates from the server for each cell, or perhaps you may look into the idea of simply using Javascript templates to render these cells, saving you the http requests.

Answer (score 2):

ALthough is not clear what you mean by "sending data to the client".
You can pass the base_template argument from your routes like:

```
@auth.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset_request():
    if path ==2:
         base_template = "jay.html"
    if path ==3:
         base_template = "blue.html"
    ...
    return render_template('auth/reset_password.html', base_template=base_template)
```

and on the template:

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

THen from your javascript frontend you just need to GET the URL.